# I don't see the performance improvement of Disruptor

Tags: java, disruptor-pattern, lmax

I know my question goes against the very fundamental claim of Disruptor API. But as I was learning about it, I wrote a program to replace my 1P-1C usecase where I was using ArrayLinkedBlockingQueue. But as I ran the program, I kept getting the total time taken with disruptor worse than ArrayLinkedBlockingQueue. I must be doing something wrong or measuring it wrong, but I am not sure what it is in my program. Does anybody have an opinion?

(It's a test program, so obviously my EventHandler is not doing anything)

```
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import com.lmax.disruptor.BusySpinWaitStrategy;
import com.lmax.disruptor.EventFactory;
import com.lmax.disruptor.EventHandler;
import com.lmax.disruptor.EventTranslator;
import com.lmax.disruptor.RingBuffer;
import com.lmax.disruptor.dsl.Disruptor;
import com.lmax.disruptor.dsl.ProducerType;

public class SPSCDisruptorTest {
    private static final int UNIT_SIZE = 1024;
    private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = UNIT_SIZE * 1024 * 16;
    private static final int ITERATIONS = BUFFER_SIZE;
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(SPSCDisruptorTest.class);

    private static class Data {
        private String data;

        public String getData() {
            return data;
        }

        public void setData(String data) {
            this.data = data;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Data [data=" + data + "]";
        }

        public final static EventFactory<Data> DATA_FACTORY = new EventFactory<Data>() {

            @Override
            public Data newInstance() {
                return new Data();
            }

        };
    }

    private static class DataEventTranslator implements EventTranslator<Data> {
        private String payload;

        public DataEventTranslator(String payload) {
            this.payload = payload;
        }

        @Override
        public void translateTo(Data d, long sequence) {
            d.setData(payload);
        }

    };

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        new SPSCDisruptorTest().testDisruptor();
        new SPSCDisruptorTest().testExecutor();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void testDisruptor() {
        ExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        Disruptor<Data> disruptor = new Disruptor<Data>(
                SPSCDisruptorTest.Data.DATA_FACTORY, BUFFER_SIZE, exec,
                ProducerType.SINGLE, new BusySpinWaitStrategy());
        disruptor.handleEventsWith(new EventHandler<Data>() {

            @Override
            public void onEvent(Data data, long sequence, boolean endOfBatch)
                    throws Exception {
            }

        });
        long t1 = System.nanoTime();
        RingBuffer<Data> buffer = disruptor.start();
        for (int i = 1; i <= ITERATIONS; i++) {
            buffer.publishEvent(new DataEventTranslator("data" + i));
        }
        logger.info("waiting for shutdown");
        disruptor.shutdown();
        logger.info("Disruptor Time (ms): " + (System.nanoTime() - t1 * 1.0)
                / 1000);
        logger.info("Disruptor is shutdown");
        exec.shutdown();
    }

    public void testExecutor() throws InterruptedException {
        ExecutorService executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 1, 0L,
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(
                        BUFFER_SIZE));
        long t1 = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 1; i <= ITERATIONS; i++) {
            executor.submit(new DataRunner("data" + i));
        }
        executor.shutdown();
        executor.awaitTermination(5000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        logger.info("Executor Time (ms): " + (System.nanoTime() - t1 * 1.0)
                / 1000);
    }

    private static class DataRunner implements Runnable {
        private String data;

        public DataRunner(String data) {
            this.data = data;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried your code on my machine I am getting better results with disruptor every time. I have used a smaller buffer size though

Answer (score 0):

You are actually Measuring it wrong. You should start your measurement after you have started the disruptor as it takes time in warmup (allocating the ring buffer). As your buffer size is huge to it takes considerable time in the warm up. try sample code  below. it should give you better time.

```
    RingBuffer<Data> buffer = disruptor.start();
    long t1 = System.nanoTime();
    for (int i = 1; i <= ITERATIONS; i++) {
        buffer.publishEvent(new DataEventTranslator("data" + i));
    }
    logger.info("waiting for shutdown");
    disruptor.shutdown();
    logger.info("Disruptor Time (ms): " + (System.nanoTime() - t1 * 1.0)
            / 1000);
```

Comment: Unfortunately I did not see much difference.
With Old approach disruptor took: 2.93E7 ms

By tracking time after disruptor.start(), I got 2.6E7 ms

So, not much difference...

Answer (score 0):

You don't have nearly enough contention to show how the lock free disruptor can help. In particular, your executor queue is as big as the iterations! All the data fits in the executor queue so it is essentially never operating with notempty/notfull conditions.

Executor service is also really bad because if the queue was smaller, you would have rejected executions. What you need to compare is 2 threads with a finite queue (maybe 1000 long) and blocking .put()/.take() calls.

To make it worse, you need batches of data (not 1 by 1) and many readers, perhaps even many writers. With contended queue access on the executor test, the disruptor should have no problem showing its performance.